# Imperfect or Preterite?

Tags: verbos, pretérito, pretérito-imperfecto

I have a problem choosing between preterite or imperfect. I know that the **imperfect** talks about conditions and the **preterite** talks about specific moments. For example(this is an example and not something I would say):

> Yo era una persona ayer. (I was a person yesterday)

Since being a person is a condition(of being a person), I used the **imperfect** tense. Should 'era'(imperfect) be switched with 'fui'(preterite) since it has a specific time(ayer or yesterday)? And if there is a condition of some sort that was part of a specific moment in time, should I use the preterite or imperfect?

Comment: If I say "yo ayer era una persona", it sounds like that was an ongoing condition that somehow has been interrupted now. If I say "yo ayer fui una persona", it sounds like you are not a person usually, but yesterday somehow you managed to become one.

Comment: @Charlie That makes sense. What if I put, "Yo era un espíritu ayer"? It's a condition that isn't ongoing(since I am no longer a spirit) and it only happened yesterday. Should I use the preterite because it only happened one time? Or should I use the imperfect since it was a condition?

Comment: Following the same logic, if you are a person and only became a spirit for one day, you can say "Ayer fui un espíritu". If you had been a spirit for a long time (or always) and have just become a person, you can say "Ayer era un espíritu". Note that this last sentence feels incomplete, as if needed to be followed by "... pero ahora soy una persona". (I've written this as a comment, but if you think this answers your question, tell me so that I can convert these comments to an answer.)

Comment: The whole point is to explain comparatively to an English speaker when to use one or the other, as I explained in my answer. The only way to do that since there is no difference in English is to ask the question: Do I mean **used to be** *in English* or not?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Here's the trick for Spanish learners**:

"was" [or were] can be simple past or imperfect:

Fui rico. = I was rich.
Era rico.= I was rich.

**So, how do you decide?**

This is how: You say to yourself **in English**, is **my meaning** or **the meaning** in what I am trying to say or write: **used to be**?

If the meaning you are trying to get across **in Spanish** is "used to be", use the imperfect. If not, use simple past.

Comment: Disregard the downvote. That person has never had to learn Spanish as an English speaker.

Comment: Again: disregard the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Nótese que ambos modos verbales pueden referirse a una condición, por ejemplo ser músico:

> Yo fui músico.

> Yo era músico.

«Era» y «fui» son **ambos** **pretéritos** (pretérito = Que ya ha pasado).  Uno es «pretérito imperfecto» (PI)  y el otro el  «pretérito perfecto simple» (PP):

- El PP se refiere a un pasado concreto, puntual, temporal, bien definido («perfecto») respecto a la propiedad semántica e inherente del evento.
- El PI se refiere a un pasado inconcreto, mal definido («imperfecto») que incluye un estado permanente, o el inicio de este.

Con «persona» y «ayer» juntas, ningún modo puede ser correcto. Su ejemplo no tiene solución, porque «persona» es una condición intrínseca y por tanto atemporal, pero  «ayer» es un tiempo definido. Si habla en pasado implica que ya no es una persona (se ha convertido en vampiro, por ejemplo) pero antes ***era*** una persona, cualquier día, no solo ayer  (tiempo indefinido), o dicho de otro modo, ***fue*** un humano, desde que nació, hasta que le mordió Drácula (tiempo definido).

No siempre es fácil discernir, incluso para los nativos, cuando se debe usar cada modo, ya que la diferencia es semántica, y no gramatical, y el marco temporal no siempre está claro:

- Mi madre *era* alta (mientras vivió).
- Mi madre *fue* muy alta (cuando nació, pero luego no creció mucho).

Más ejemplos:

> **Fui** el primero en llegar al cine (ayer)

> **Era** el niño más feliz del mundo (cada vez que me hacían regalos).

> El castillo era atacado en las incursiones enemigas.

> El castillo fue atacado en la incursión enemiga.

Es el contexto de tiempo (marco o escenario) lo que te dice qué debes usar:

> Era un idiota  cuando me emborrachaba (muchas veces).

> Fui un idiota cuando le dije eso a mi amigo (una vez).

Si este marco de tiempo no está claro, puede ser  intercambiables, a veces de forma sutil. En el siguiente texto,  los dos modos verbales solo hablan de condiciones:

> Mi padre era artista. Fue pintor, músico y poeta.

Pero al contrario, no encajan bien:

> Mi padre fue artista. Era pintor, músico y poeta.

Y es que se puede ser artista siempre y pintor una vez, pero no es posible ser pintor siempre y artista solo a ratos (bueno, algunos  pintores  son cualquier cosa menos artistas, pero eso nos llevaría a otro debate...)

Comment: No se explica con todo esto porque was puede ser uno u otro.